# Ionic 2 erro TypeScript ao compilar

Tags: ionic2, typescript

Estou fazendo a construção do menu lateral (side-menu) a primeira etapa de inserir o botão e a primeira aba foi tranquilo, porém na parte de abrir essas abas como por exemplo "page one" ou "page two" dá dois tipos de erros alternados.

Um é "*`;` expected*", ou seja, ponto e virgula sendo esperado, só que no código já está lá o `;`

[image: erro ponto virgula]

mas ainda sim o erro aparece o código em questão é:

```
openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
}
```

O outro erro que comumente me aparece é que o método no caso `openPage` não está

[image: erro metodo]

Comment: Finalize e rode o server novamente: `ionic server`

Comment: Mesmo reiniciando o processo, mantem-se o mesmo erro

Comment: Então é porque realmente está faltando um ponto e virgula.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro Type Script Ionic 2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197489/erro-type-script-ionic-2)